# How To Style Modern UI RadialGaugeChart

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, charts, modern-ui

I'm using Modern UI Charts in my project ([Modern UI Charts](https://modernuicharts.codeplex.com/)), and I'm trying to change the chart **foreground** and palette based on **ValueMember**.

I have a converter:

```
public class MetricsColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        //Dim num As Integer
        string color = null;
        decimal intValue = default(decimal);
        if (decimal.TryParse(value.ToString(), intValue)) {
            if (intValue <= 60.0) {
                return "Red";
            } else if (intValue >= 60.01 && intValue < 80.0) {
                return "Yellow";
            } else if (intValue >= 80.01) {
                return "Green";
            }
        }

        return color;
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And my xaml with a chart:

```
<chart:RadialGaugeChart
       ChartTitleVisibility="Collapsed"
       ChartLegendVisibility="Collapsed"
       ToolTipFormat="{}Caption: {0}, Value: '{1}', Series: '{2}', Percentage: {3:P2}"
       HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="5,5,5,5" Height="170" >
    <chart:RadialGaugeChart.Style>
           <Style TargetType="{x:Type chart:RadialGaugeChart}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=ProductivitySeries, Path=ValueMember, Converter={StaticResource MetricsConverter}}" Value="Green">
                       <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource Flat_GreenAccentBrush}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=ProductivitySeries, Path=ValueMember, Converter={StaticResource MetricsConverter}} "Value="Yellow">
                       <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource Flat_MetricYellowBrush}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=ProductivitySeries, Path=ValueMember, Converter={StaticResource MetricsConverter}}" Value="Red">
                       <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource Flat_MetricRedBrush}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
           </Style>
    </chart:RadialGaugeChart.Style>
<chart:RadialGaugeChart.Series>
    <chart:ChartSeries 
          Name="ProductivitySeries" 
          SeriesTitle="Productivity" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding TeamLeaderViewM.TeamLeaderMetrics}" 
          DisplayMember="TeamLeader" 
          ValueMember="Productivity"/>
    </chart:RadialGaugeChart.Series>
</chart:RadialGaugeChart>
```

Unfortunately, nothing is changing here. Color is the same, all the time.
How can I implement this to my charts?

Thank you for suuggestions

Comment: Can you confirm, your converter is working correctly?

Comment: Yes. I've check it with label and the foreground is changing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to modify the default `PlotterArea` style as shown below:

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    xmlns:MetroChart="clr-namespace:De.TorstenMandelkow.MetroChart;assembly=De.TorstenMandelkow.MetroChart" 
    x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>

    <ResourceDictionary>

        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/De.TorstenMandelkow.MetroChart;component/Themes/Generic.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

        <local:MetricsColorConverter x:Key="Converter1"></local:MetricsColorConverter>

        <x:Array x:Key="SampleData1" Type="{x:Type local:MyData}">
            <local:MyData TeamLeader="Team A" Productivity="50"></local:MyData>
            <local:MyData TeamLeader="Team B" Productivity="75"></local:MyData>
            <local:MyData TeamLeader="Team C" Productivity="90"></local:MyData>
        </x:Array>

        <Style x:Key="RadialGaugeChartPlotterAreaStyle1" TargetType="MetroChart:PlotterArea">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="MetroChart:PlotterArea">
                        <MetroChart:FadingListView Style="{StaticResource FadingListViewStyle}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ParentChart.DataPointGroups, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}">
                            <MetroChart:FadingListView.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </MetroChart:FadingListView.ItemsPanel>
                            <MetroChart:FadingListView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <Border Grid.Row="0" Visibility="{Binding Path=ShowCaption, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Caption}" Style="{StaticResource SeriesTitleStyle}" />
                                        </Border>
                                        <MetroChart:FadingListView Style="{StaticResource FadingListViewStyle}"
                                            x:Name="itemsControl" 
                                            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataPoints}"
                                            Margin="5"
                                            Grid.Row="1">
                                            <MetroChart:FadingListView.ItemsPanel>
                                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                                    <!--<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />-->
                                                    <MetroChart:UniformGridPanel Orientation="Horizontal" MinimalGridWidth="150.0" />
                                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                            </MetroChart:FadingListView.ItemsPanel>
                                            <MetroChart:FadingListView.ItemTemplate>
                                                <DataTemplate>
                                                    <Grid>
                                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                                            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                        <MetroChart:RadialGaugePiece
                                                    Grid.Row="0"
                                                    Margin="5"
                                                    Background="{Binding Path=Value, Converter={StaticResource Converter1}}"
                                                    SelectedBrush="{Binding Path=SelectedBrush}"  
                                                    Value="{Binding Path=Value}"
                                                    IsClickedByUser="{Binding Path=IsClickedByUser, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                                    IsSelected="{Binding Path=IsSelected}"
                                                    ClientWidth="180"
                                                    ClientHeight="180" 
                                                    x:Name="radial">
                                                        </MetroChart:RadialGaugePiece>
                                                        <Border Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0 0 0 10">
                                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=SeriesCaption}" />
                                                        </Border>
                                                    </Grid>
                                                </DataTemplate>
                                            </MetroChart:FadingListView.ItemTemplate>
                                        </MetroChart:FadingListView>
                                    </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </MetroChart:FadingListView.ItemTemplate>
                        </MetroChart:FadingListView>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

    </ResourceDictionary>

</Window.Resources>

<Grid>

    <MetroChart:RadialGaugeChart ChartTitle="My Sample" 
                                 ChartSubTitle="Productivity" 
                                 HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                 VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                 PlotterAreaStyle="{StaticResource RadialGaugeChartPlotterAreaStyle1}">
        <MetroChart:RadialGaugeChart.Series>
            <MetroChart:ChartSeries Name="ProductivitySeries"
                               SeriesTitle="My Series" 
                               DisplayMember="TeamLeader" 
                               ValueMember="Productivity" 
                               ItemsSource="{StaticResource SampleData1}" />
        </MetroChart:RadialGaugeChart.Series>
    </MetroChart:RadialGaugeChart>

</Grid>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! One additional question, I guess I'm able now to add additional text under Percentage in the gauge? thank you in advance

Comment: Yes, whatever is assigned to the `TeamLeader` property in your `ViewModel` will appear under the gauge.